# iOS8 view is fine but is smaller on iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5, ios8

I am currently working on an iOS application with a Deployment Target of 7.1. Most of my testing has been performed in an iOS8 environment with no issues. I hooked up an iOS7 (5s) test device and found that the view is showing itself as through the phone is a 3.5 (4). I'm not sure what the difference is between iOS7 and iOS8 that would cause this but I can't seem to find a solution. I have rebooted the device, reinstalled the app, and made sure all constraints were set properly in the dev environment. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use splash screen images not splash screen xib. In my case I have the same problem iOS7 device has black stripe at top and bottom. So I change the settings for splash screen and used images as a splash screen instead of xib and it solved my problem.

Comment: Did you mean that the problem only occurred on device and not on simulator?

Comment: No I have faced the same problem in simulator also

Comment: Thanks, I thought the problem was on the device. I wonder why people claim that using splash screen xib is not a good way. Would you happen to know?

Comment: Actually i havn't tried the splash screen xib properly, i think there are some sizing rules which will fix the issue.

Comment: Hi @souvickcse. I did this as suggested and it still seems to be running on a 3.5in screen when running under 7.1.x. This is both in the simulator and on the device itself. I should note that this happens in full app usage and not just on launch. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app has a launch screen for 4" devices. Otherwise it will default to 3.5" devices.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a LaunchImage in the xcassets file. That will solve your problem.

[image]